# Unity - How to call multiple parameters for UI Button with single string

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, split

Unity button can only take one parameter from the inspector but I heard that you can use a singular string which then needs to be split up and then used as multiple parameters. How can I do that?

For example If I put this in one string seperated by comma:  "John,Attack,1"   (What this basically means is that For character named John, it will change the Attack stat for that character by +1). So it takes character's name, Stat type and amount as parameter.

I already have the methods set up just need an example and explanation on how something like this can be done.

EDIT: With TEEBQNE's suggestion I was able to get it working, this is what I have done. But if you have better ways or improvement on the code then feel free to share.

```
public void ChangeStat(string phrase)
    {
        string[] words = phrase.Split(',');

        //For the 3 parameters need: StringType:cName, EnumType:stat, intType:amount
        string cName = words[0];
        Stat stat = (Stat)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Stat), words[1]);
        int amount = int.Parse(words[2]);

        //if the dictionary contains a valid character name then add the stat level
        if (CharacterDatabase.ContainsKey(cName))
        {
            //Save previous value
            int previousValue = CharacterDatabase[cName].Stats[stat];

            Debug.Log("Character found!");
            //Add the stat by the amount
            CharacterDatabase[cName].Stats[stat] += amount;
            Debug.Log(CharacterDatabase[cName].CharacterBase.Name + "'s " + stat + " level is now: " + CharacterDatabase[cName].Stats[stat] + "(Before: " + previousValue + " )");
            return;
        }
        //Else the character name was not valid in the dictionary DB
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Character NOT found!");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split) ? And you can wrap your callback in a lambda/delegate like `button.onClick.AddListener(() => YourMethod(as, many, parameters, as, you, like));` .. a bit unclear what exactly you are asking

Comment: Sorry about that I wasn't exactly sure how to describe it. TEEBQNE has provided a solution that is working and I updated my post with the code I did using his suggestion. Hopefully looking at that method will clear it up and I appreciate other suggestions and ways I can do this. I will also try the callback style that you mentioned

Comment: You definitely want to go for a delegate ... string based stuff is always .. well, shitty in performance, readability, maintainability, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are referring to is a delimiter which is a character or sequence of characters to define a split between important data. You can add multiple parameters to a button doing this as a string or you can add a delegate in code and add whatever data you would like from there.

To split a string in c# over a character, just get an array of strings and use the code.

```
string[] words = phrase.Split(',');
```

In your example, you posted `"John,Attack,1"`, so what this above code will do, should convert it into a string array as {John, Attack, 1}. Then the onClick would just be a string. When you get into the onClick, you should know what types each index is in the array, so just convert them back. I would use `System.Convert.To[YourTypeHere](stringHere);` The issue here is it is harder to serialize types such as other gameobject or components.

To explain the other method of having a multi parameter function for a button, you add all of the data in code.

```
// the button that triggers this
[SerializeField] private Button myButton = null;

// data to pass in - assigned in the inspector
[SerializeField] private GameObject obj = null;
[SerializeField] private string strObj = "";
[SerializeField] private int intObj = 0;


private void Start()
{
    myButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate{OurCallback(obj, strObj, intObj);});
}

// our actual onclick
private void OurCallback(GameObject obj, string str, int num)
{
    // code
}
```

The above method seems a bit redundant to pass the data as a parameter when it is already in the code. A use case I can think of is if a manager assigns the parameters in some sort of Init() function in its `Start()` or `Awake()`, then the button contains and holds this data already in the callback with no extra work after it is set.

Let me know if you have questions about either implementation. Knowing more about your situation can help narrow down which works better.

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what I needed. Read my updated post again and that is what I have done to get it working. If you have other suggestions let me know but this is working for me.

Comment: My only real feedback for the snippet is to consider if the data read in will ever not be the type you expect. Using int.parse can fail which throws an exception if it is not able to parse to an int. If the data is guaranteed to be an int, there is no issue, but if there is a chance it wont be for some odd reason. I would recommend using a [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0).

Comment: The one question I have is what type is `CharacterDatabase`? Does it contain another data structure that holds other dictionaries?

Comment: CharacterDatabase is a dictionary of all my Characters. Basically acting as my main Character database where everything for all characters is managed like CRUD operations like Changing stats, adding to party/group from the database and removing characters from my party/group etc. The Project is a rpg type game with Turn based combat.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I am a bit confused then why you need to iterate over each entry in the dictionary. What is the Key value of the database? Can you not just access the character's data by their name? So `CharacterDatabase['name'].accessDataHere`? Or is the CharacterDatabase a wrapper for other dictionaries that hold character data?

Comment: I have two lists, one is a list type and the other is dictionary. `public Dictionary<string, Character> CharacterDatabase;` and  `[SerializeField] List<Character> characterList;` I basically make sure the characterList is linked to the dictionary one so its easier to manage characters by simply using their character name as key. The foreach loop is just there to ensure that a character exists in the dictionary so mainly for validation/debug purposes incase I spell the name of a character wrong or its not in the database which means I forgot to link scriptableobjects to my characterList.

Comment: If the dictionary has the name as the key you don't need to iterate through any list. You just need to check if the name is contained in the dictionary. It immediately tell you if it exists or not. You won't need to iterate over any list.

Comment: You're right, I made the changes. Thanks for that. I thought iterating was needed to get access to the "ContainsKey()". Haven't really used dictionary a whole lot before so guess I need to do more of my homework on it.